# How to pass an argument calling a function using ArgParse?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I'm trying to call function_3 with an argument but i'm receiving a error unrecognized arguments. I'm calling this way: `python script.py --pass test`

```
import argparse
import sys

def function_1():
    print('Function 1')

def function_2():
    print('Function 2')

def function_3(arg):
    print(f'Function 3 {arg}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    
    parser_f1 = subparsers.add_parser('fc1', help='Function 1')
    parser_f1.set_defaults(func=function_1)

    parser_f2 = subparsers.add_parser('fc2', help='Function 2')
    parser_f2.set_defaults(func=function_2)

    parser_f3 = subparsers.add_parser('fc3', help='Function 3')
    parser_f3.add_argument("pass", help="function 3 argument")
    parser_f3.set_defaults(func=function_3)
        
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        sys.argv.append('--help')

    options = parser.parse_args()
    options.func()
```

### Error

```
usage: argtest.py [-h] {fc1,fc2,fc3} ...
argtest.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --arg
```

Comment: show the full error message, including usage

Comment: sorry, one minute

Comment: Have you considered using click instead? https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/

Answer (score 1):

First, your `pass` option is only available to the `fc3` subparser, so rather than `python script.py --pass test`, you would want:

```
python script.py fc3 --pass test
```

But you've defined a *positional* argument, not a command line option. You need to either call your script like this:

```
python script.py fc3 test
```

Or you need to fix your code:

```
parser_f3.add_argument('--pass', help='function 3 argument')
```

That would allow you run `python script.py fc3 --pass test`.

---

There are still additional problems with the code; your `function3` function requires an argument, but you're calling `options.func()` with no arguments, which will result in a `TypeError` exception.

Comment: What constitutes a positional argument (name) or a command line option (flag) is highlighted in [name or flags](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags).

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest doing it this way, I'd personally suggest just using click instead, but this is one method for doing it I guess...

```py
import sys
from argparse import ArgumentParser


def parse_args():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "-f", "--function", type=str, help="name of the function to call", default="echo"
    )
    parser.add_argument("func_args", nargs="*")
    return parser.parse_args(args=None if sys.argv[1:] else ["--help"])


def echo(*args):
    print(' '.join(*args))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
    eval(f"{args.function}({args.func_args})")
```

This approach feels fragile and wrong to me, but I believe this is line with the behavior you're asking for.